# Trying to automate joining a discord guild but keep getting my account verification locked. Any solution/way to get the missing headers?

Tags: post, python-requests, discord, authorization

Previously a simple post request to https://discord.com/api/v6/invites/INVITEHERE with just the token worked fine. It still does work in that it adds my account to the guild but it also gets my account verification locked... I believe the problem is that I should be supplying:

x-super-properties, x-fingerprint, and a cloudflare cookie

and lacking one or all of these values is making my bot look like a bot.

Is their any solution? I attempted to obtain these values by sending a login request... but I do not seem to receive them (besides the cookie) in any browser requests. I have no idea where these values come from.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the request contains the following headers, an account will join the server regardless of the Authorization token used.

```
POST /api/v9/invites/some_guild HTTP/1.1
Host: canary.discord.com
Cookie: __dcfduid=some_cloudflare_cookie1; __sdcfduid=some_cloudflare_cookie2; locale=en-US
Content-Length: 2
X-Super-Properties: some_valid_value
X-Context-Properties: some_valid_value
Authorization: some_auth_token
X-Debug-Options: bugReporterEnabled
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: some_user_agent
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Origin: https://www.discord.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.discord.com/channels/some_guild/some_channel
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close

{}
```

So the steps would be:

1. Join a guild with a certain account and capture the request headers values
2. Iterate through a list of tokens you want to join the guild with

Note that the `X-Context-Properties` contains the `guild_id` and the landing channel page and is hence **unique** to each guild, so there is no way to guess it without joining the guild once first.